# how to show another view when clicked on pin annotation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, mapkit

i have added a detail button on my pin annotation. i want to go to another view. when i click on it, following code doesn't work. i don't know where is the problem.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
    if(annotation != mapview.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
        pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
            pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;

        //instatiate a detail-disclosure button and set it to appear on right side of annotation
        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

    }

    return pinAnnotation;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

    if ([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure){
    annotationViewController *detailView=[[annotationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"annotationViewController" bundle:nil];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
    [detailView release];
}
}
```

Comment: Did you set the `MKMapViewDelegate` delegate

Comment: i did mapview.delegate=self; in my view controller but it give me warning

Comment: assigning id<MKmapviewdelegate> from incompatable type "viewController"

Comment: in the `.h` file add `<MKMapViewDelegate>` .It will not give error and your code will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control` is a delegate method. That's why you need to set your mapview's delegate to the class that implements this method (here `self`), in order for it to be called.

You also need to tell the class that you're implementing the `MKMapViewDelegate` methods. To do so, in you .h, change this line :

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
```

To :

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

Your method should get called now.